# Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link not playing well with Firefox - throwing exception

Tags: security, firefox, exception, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

Just now I tried Browser Link with Firefox 27.0.1 while debugging a simple ASP.NET MVC app.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 1.

Here's Browser Link Dashboard:

[image]

I tried changing something in a razor view, pressed Ctrl+S and went to the browser to see if the page had changed accordingly but...

this is what i see in Firebug:

```
http://localhost:6194/85d266397ee64f32b2f4ffdedc974643/arterySignalR/negotiate?requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26530%2Fgis&browserName=Firefox&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1394212700505

[13:56:43 GMT-0300] Browser Link:
Exception thrown in callback method pullStyleData:
[Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012
(SecurityError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
```

Then I saw this error:

```
401 Unauthorized 82ms   
browserLink (line 37)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:26530/85d266397ee64f32b2f4ffdedc974643/arterySignalR/ping?requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26530%2Fgis&browserName=Firefox&_=1394211620626"
```

I'm running Visual Studio as Administrator.

What's the deal and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was bug in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 as Mads Kristensen told me [here](https://twitter.com/mkristensen/status/441989185272950784).

So the solution is to go grab [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 CTP 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42023).