# Web Essentials 2013, BrowserLink, 0x80530012 (SecurityError)

Tags: exploit, web-essentials

I have seen in Firebug the following exception:

```
[10:23:26 GMT+0200] Browser Link: Exception thrown in callback method setPixelPusingMode: [Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
```

[The solution suggested in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256392/visual-studio-2013-browser-link-not-playing-well-with-firefox-throwing-excepti) did not work and then I installed the latest VS Professional 2013 Update(3 RC) and this did not work as well.

Any ideas to fix this?